# image changes multiple times by clicking different words

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner to javascript. I am trying to have a situation where there is a series of words and each word changes the background to a different image when clicked. Currently one of the functions are working, but I can't seem to get the other ones to work as well. I know I am doing something wrong but I am not sure what to change.

I have looked through several other questions and they seem to use more complicated coding or using jquery. I want to try and do this in the most simple way possible and i feel like this is a good way to go. Thanks!

Here's what I have:

```js
var pic = document.getElementById('pic');
var word = document.getElementById('clickme1');

word.onclick = function() {
  pic.src = "image1.jpg"
}

var pic2 = document.getElementById('pic');
var word2 = document.getElementById('clickme2');

word.onclick = function() {
  pic2.src = "image2.jpg"
}

var pic3 = document.getElementById('pic');
var word3 = document.getElementById('clickme3');

word.onclick = function() {
  pic3.src = "image3.jpg"
}

var pic4 = document.getElementById('pic');
var word4 = document.getElementById('clickme4');

word.onclick = function() {
  pic4.src = "image4.jpg"
}
```

```html
<image id="pic" width="1000" height "400" src="image.jpg" /></image>

<div id="container">hello,
  <span id="clickme1">heres the first word I want clicked on</span>
  <span id="clickme2">second word</span> 
  <span id="clickme3">third word</span>
  <span id="clickme4">forth</span>
</div>
```

Comment: images  in html uses `img` tag not `image`

Comment: There are 2 error in code 1. img not image and other is variable your using word for every event

Comment: Yeah, also you just need 1 reference to the image.  No need for pic 1-4, just use:

var pic = document.getElementById('pic');

Answer (score 2):

You would try the following:

1. Fix your `<img>` tag to use the proper name.
2. Remove the multiple references to your `img#pic`.

### Notes

1. I used placeholder images to see what is going on, when you update the `src` attribute of the image.
2. I added some style for hovering to easily distinguish which words you are clicking on.
3. I reduced the size of the image so that the text is visible on the screen.

```js
var pic = document.getElementById('pic');

var word = document.getElementById('clickme1');
word.onclick = function() {
  pic.src = "http://placehold.it/180x120/AA4444/E9EBFF.png&text=Image+1";
}

var word2 = document.getElementById('clickme2');
word2.onclick = function() {
  pic.src = "http://placehold.it/180x120/44AA44/E9EBFF.png&text=Image+2"
}

var word3 = document.getElementById('clickme3');
word3.onclick = function() {
  pic.src = "http://placehold.it/180x120/4444AA/E9EBFF.png&text=Image+3"
}

var word4 = document.getElementById('clickme4');
word4.onclick = function() {
  pic.src = "http://placehold.it/180x120/AA7744/E9EBFF.png&text=Image+4"
}
```

```css
span[id^="clickme"]:hover {
  background: #FF0;
}
```

```html
<img id="pic" width="180" height="120" src="http://placehold.it/180x120/445566/E9EBFF.png&text=Default" />

<div id="container">Hello,
  <span id="clickme1">heres the first word I want clicked on</span>
  <span id="clickme2">second word</span> 
  <span id="clickme3">third word</span>
  <span id="clickme4">forth</span>.
</div>
```

---

## Dynamic Approach

Since you are repeating code, it is better to use a `class` rather than an `id`. The following is an HTML5 implementation, using the data attribute along with an array of images as reference.

For each of the elements with the `.click-me` class, a click listener is added along with a `data-pos` attribute to keep track of the position. This position will help determine which image to load, based on the words that were clicked.

```js
var pic = document.getElementById('pic');
var clickMeElements = document.querySelectorAll('span.click-me');

var images = [
  "http://placehold.it/180x120/AA4444/E9EBFF.png&text=Image+1",
  "http://placehold.it/180x120/44AA44/E9EBFF.png&text=Image+2",
  "http://placehold.it/180x120/4444AA/E9EBFF.png&text=Image+3",
  "http://placehold.it/180x120/AA7744/E9EBFF.png&text=Image+4"
];

for (var i = 0; i < clickMeElements.length; i++) {
  var clickMe = clickMeElements[i];
  
  clickMe.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    pic.src = images[event.target.getAttribute('data-pos')];
  });
  
  clickMe.setAttribute('data-pos', i)
}
```

```css
span.click-me:hover {
  background: #FF0;
}
```

```html
<img id="pic" width="180" height="120" src="http://placehold.it/180x120/445566/E9EBFF.png&text=Default" />

<div id="container">Hello,
  <span class="click-me">heres the first word I want clicked on</span>
  <span class="click-me">second word</span> 
  <span class="click-me">third word</span>
  <span class="click-me">forth</span>.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers are capturing all that is wrong with your code:

1. You need to use `<img/>` instead of `<image/>`
2. Your pic variable does not need to be renamed - you are using a single `img` element whose `src` is being changed on click.
3. I believe there was an issue with your `word` variable naming, but it looks like you've changed that now.

Answer (score -1):

You are using wrong the 'words' variable:

```
<script>

var pic = document.getElementById('pic');
var word =document.getElementById('clickme1');

word.onclick = function(){
pic.src = "image1.jpg"
}

var pic2 = document.getElementById('pic');
var word2 =document.getElementById('clickme2');

//word.onclick = function(){
word2.onclick = function(){
pic2.src = "image2.jpg"
}

var pic3 = document.getElementById('pic');
var word3 =document.getElementById('clickme3');

//word.onclick = function(){
word3.onclick = function(){
pic3.src = "image3.jpg"
}

var pic4 = document.getElementById('pic');
var word4 =document.getElementById('clickme4');

//word.onclick = function(){
word4.onclick = function(){
pic4.src = "image4.jpg"
}
</script>
```

Comment: You might want to be more specific here - what variable is OP using incorrectly? More information would be helpful for the OP to learn what they are doing wrong.

Answer (score -1):

The issue you have is your function, rename to unique names:

```
var pic = document.getElementById('pic');
var word =document.getElementById('clickme1');

word1.onclick = function(){
   pic.src = "image1.jpg"
}

var pic2 = document.getElementById('pic');
var word2 =document.getElementById('clickme2');

word2.onclick = function(){
   pic2.src = "image2.jpg"
}

var pic3 = document.getElementById('pic');
var word3 =document.getElementById('clickme3');

word3.onclick = function(){
  pic3.src = "image3.jpg"
}

var pic4 = document.getElementById('pic');
var word4 =document.getElementById('clickme4');

word4.onclick = function(){
   pic4.src = "image4.jpg"
}
```